# How to get the alt value from this string?

Tags: string, linq

```
    <img src=\"%24FILEBASE%moga.jpg\" alt=\"moga.jpg\" width=\"882\" height=\"324\">
```

I need this value: "moga.jpg"
Note: There is no closing tag for this. So, I was not able to successfully come up with a linq expression. Is there a cleaner way using linq or regex or something else?

Comment: linq? what language/environment do u need this in?

Comment: in which language? be more specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if yout HTML is perfectly formatted, you can match it using regular expressions if you want! No problem. But @rexcfnghk advice is correct in the pratical world...

If someone wants to use Regular Expression... try this example!
You could explore the `collection` better to check if the content is there, of course... just explore the MatchCollection class.

```
string htmlNode = "<img src=\"%24FILEBASE%moga.jpg\" alt=\"moga.jpg\" width=\"882\" height=\"324\">";
MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(htmlNode, "src=\\\"%24FILEBASE%(.*?)\\\"", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
string result = collection[0].Groups[1].Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse HTML. Don't use LINQ-To-XML or [regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

```
var document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(/* your html string */);

var navigator = (HtmlNodeNavigator)document.CreateNavigator();
var value = navigator.SelectSingleNode("//img/@src").Value;
```